# Quicksort with custom filter

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I need to make quicksort but with a custom filter.
During compilation I get an error on `filter (>=x) xs`.

```
--sort with two filters
quicksort (x:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++[x] ++ (quicksort greater)
                  where lesser  = filter (<x) xs
                        greater = filter (>=x) xs

--sort with custom filter
csort f (x:xs) = (csort f lesser) ++ [x] ++ (csort f greater)
                    where lesser  = [e | e <- xs, f x e]
                          greater = [e | e <- xs, not $ f x e]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Note that `filter (f x) xs` is the same as `[e | e <- xs, f x e]`, and `filter (not . f x) xs` is the same as `[e | e <- xs, not $ f x e]`. I personally avoid list comprehensions unless combining more than one list.

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it with the homework tag. It also helps to add the compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems I think might be troubling you.

First of all, loading a file with your definitions into ghci, I try

```
ghci> csort (>= x) [2,1,3]

<interactive>:1:10: Not in scope: 'x'
```

The way you wrote it, `f` takes two parameters. And indeed `x` is not in scope here. So the custom filter function should be simply `(>=)`.

```
ghci> csort (>=) [2,1,3]
***Exception: blahblah: Non-exhaustive patterns in function csort
```

Now the real problem: non-exhaustive patterns. What does this mean? You've written a definition of how to sort a list with at least one element. But how do you sort a list with no elements? Simple, you ignore the custom filter function, and simply produce an empty list. Since an empty list has no elements, it is already "sorted".

```
csort _ [] = []
```

Once I added that line to the source file, it suddenly worked. The pattern `[]` compliments the pattern `(x:xs)`, and those two patterns, together, are exhaustive (a list is either empty, or it has at least one element).

```
ghci> csort (>=) [2,1,3]
[1,2,3]
ghci> csort (<) [2,1,3]
[3,2,1]
ghci> quickCheck (\xs -> csort (<) xs == (reverse $ csort (>) xs))
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

---

Here's my sort.hs file:

```
csort _ [] = []
csort f (x:xs) = csort f lesser ++ [x] ++ csort f greater
  where lesser  = [e | e <- xs, f x e]
        greater = [e | e <- xs, not $ f x e]
```

I have no idea why you would still have errors; this works perfectly well for me.

Comment: but I've got an error on quicksort. not csort.
`parse error on input '='`

Comment: OT: Doesn't the defaulting in GHCI cause the QuickCheck property to use [()] (which is obviously no good)?

Comment: @JonasDuregård yes you're right. Throw a type annotation in there to make it a legitimate test.