# Haskell parse error on input '='

Tags: function, haskell

This is a Quicksort function. But I've got an error at 5:46

```
--sort function
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++[x] ++ (quicksort greater)
                      where lesser = filter (<) xs
                                 greater = filter (>=) xs
```

What's the problem? 
It seems that the function is correct.

Comment: Due to immutability, this actually *isn't* a Quicksort function, but that's a discussion for when you're more comfortable with the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have a simple whitespace error.... `lesser` and `greater` need to be indented equally, so that they begin on the same column.

Comment: But they are intended equally. it's only here they are not equal

Comment: you must have a tab character somewhere, because when they are not indented equally, that is the exact error I receive.

Comment: @Артём Царионов - Make sure you're using spaces instead of tabs. You can set this up in your editor if you're worried about your thumbs. When the tabs are gone from your source code, then you'll know if your indentation is correct or not.

Comment: @Артём Царионов I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure your best option, but I'm sure it's not Notepad.  This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734309/haskell-ide-for-windows

Comment: I've copied this code to program with csort and renamed it. And I've got two errors now - `couldn't match expected type Bool` for 3rd string and the same error for 4th

Comment: @Артём Царионов: I didn't say this was the only problem with your function... just the reason for the error stated in the title of this question.  I don't think you had this problem in this similar question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841388/quicksort-with-custom-filter